# why does View::make() not exist in laravel docs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-views

why does View::make() not exist in laravel docs?
I have gone through on xVersion/views pages of all versions of Laravel docs, but I couldn't find any statement about View::make(). who can explain to me how it works?

additional info, I'm learning Aimeos Laravel package.
I don't think View::make is from Aimeos packages.
because, I see [image]

composer.json

```
> "require": {
>         "php": "^7.2.5",
>         "aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "dev-master",
>         "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
>         "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
>         "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
>         "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
>         "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
>         "laravel/ui": "^2.4"
>     },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things in Laravel have multiple ways of referencing them.

The documentation prefers the use of the cleaner, less verbose [`view()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-view), but you can use `View::make` if you prefer.

The API docs for `View::make` are at https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/View/Factory.html#method_make.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: not that, I know it, I meant this. https://imgur.com/PX9O0m1

Comment: @Murod That's documented at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#views

Answer (score 2):

`View::make` is calling a `make` method on the `View` facade. This was how views were referenced in Laravel 4.x, but Laravel 5.x introduced the global `view` helper that does the same thing, just with a few less keystrokes.

Therefore, `View::make('shop::page.privacy')` is the same as `view('shop::page.privacy')`.

Comment: Where? In `View::make` or the view name itself?